# How to apply transformations directly on mesh data?

Tags: objects, transforms

I need to load some COLLADA files into a program that does not support any transformations (because it does not support scaling). I want to export these objects from a .blend file.

Is there a way to apply the transformations directly on the mesh vertex data in blender before exporting the objects to .dae?

An example:

```
Scale(2,2) * triangle{(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)} => triangle{(0,0), (0,2), (2,2)}
```

Comment: What about `Ctrl+A` > *Apply*?

Comment: I'm very inexperienced with Blender, so I really don't know what I'm doing here. It looks better now, but still a bit off. The exported transformations do not equal the identity matrix. They still contain translations although I checked location, rotation and scale. Any advice?

Comment: Finally, after applying them via the dropdown menu, everything works fine. Thanks a lot! You really saved me some hours of work :-)

Comment: Enabling in the tool panel or in the `F6` menu works for me.. Are you using the latest `2.69` release?

Comment: I'm using 2.67 (will update asap) and checking the "Apply Object Transform"s resulted in the error mentioned above (translations weren't removed). CTRL + A and applying the transformations one after another works fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> [Apply](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Reset_Object_Transformations#Apply_Options)*, then checking the transforms you want to apply with <kbd>F6</kbd> or in *3D View > Tool shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Redo menu*:

[image]