# Mesh changes its shape in game engine

Tags: game-engine

I'm learning to use the game engine and I don't know why a mesh change its shape when I press P key.

This happened when I subdivided the red mesh. I subdivided it because I want the ball collide the red wall but I don't want a rigid wall, I want a soft wall.

[image]
[image]

Here is the file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28811
(The ball moves with left and right arrows)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you modified the mesh in some way after changing the physics *Type*. To fix, just simply apply the scale on the object, you can quickly do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Scale* or from the *3d view* header choose *Object > Apply > Scale*.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the object mode transforms directly to the mesh data with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (see [How to apply transformations directly on mesh data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3646/599)).

The *Apply Transformation* button in the rigid body tools panel applies any *3D view* rigid body transformations to the object. For example, if you use rigid body physics (in the 3D view, not the game engine) to drop an object to the ground, then you can set that to be the initial state of the object by pressing that button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*>Visual Transform*).